How to connect clickhouse to rabbitMQ with ssl
I'm trying to connect to rabbitMQ but in our production system in order to connect to rabbitMQ we need to provide custom CA file, client cert and key.
I tried to modify the config.xml as:
<openssl>
    <client>
        <caConfig>/path/to/cafile.crt</caConfig>
        <certificateFile>/path/to/cert.pem</certificateFile>
        <privateKey>/path/to/key.pem</privateKey>
    </client>
</openssl>

But when trying to connect using:
RabbitMQ setting rabbitmq_addres = 'ampqs://user:password@host:port/vhost
I get the error:
tls handshake failure:contrib/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:865:SSL alert number 40
But if I am trying to connect from the server directly with openssl:
openssl s_client -connect host:port -CAfile /path/to/CAfile.crt -cert /path/to/cert.pem -key /path/to/key.pem
It connects just fine.
What am I missing? Am I using the config.xml incorrectly?

according to
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/rabbitmq#creating-a-table
CREATE TABLE ... SETTINGS rabbitmq_secure =1 or SETINGS rabbitmq_address = 'amqps://user:password@host:port/vhost'
